How to make html2canvas faster when generating a PDF using HTML tables in my angular application using jsPDF?
I have a Angular application which presents a paginated table to the user. My user needs to be able to create a PDF report with each paginated table per page, scaled to fit 1 table per page.
Currently I have this implementation using JSPDF:
  async downloadCustomTablePdf() {

    const pdf = new jsPDF('l', 'mm', 'a4');


    let temp = [];
    let count = 1;

    for (let i in this.fData) {

      if (count > 18) {
        count = 1
        this.fDataReport = temp;

        const table: any = document.getElementById('myTable');
        table.style.width = '100%';

        await html2canvas(table).then(async (canvas) => {
          const imageData = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 0.5);

          const imgWidth = pdf.internal.pageSize.getWidth() - 20; 
          const imgHeight = canvas.height * imgWidth / canvas.width;

          pdf.addImage(imageData, 'PNG', 10, 10, imgWidth, imgHeight);
          temp = [];

          pdf.addPage('l');

        });

      }

      if (count <= 18) {
        temp.push(this.fData[i]);
        count++
      }

    }

    pdf.save('table.pdf');
  }


essentially the current code loops through by data object and populates the Table and every 18 rows a "screenshot" is taken and added to the PDF page.
But it seems that for each page it takes about 1 second to process. Wondering if there is faster way of doing this? Potentially without the image method. Its imperative that each tabled is scaled to fit on only 1 page.
Thanks for any help on this.
